# Just another web startup - platform comparison

Tags: java, .net, comparison, startup

I'm looking to do a web startup which involves something along the lines of an ecommerce site, yet a little more in depth than that. While it's something that I would rather not go into detail with in terms of the initial idea, I can specify (on a basic level) what would be required of the website. If you have any observations or opinions derived from personal experience, which relate to what you see here, I'd appreciate it if you could share these.

- Paypal's API interaction (definitely).

  - From what I've read about their API, integration with it into their website is VERY expensive, so I'd probably hold off on that until I've (hopefully) generated money and write my own simple credit-card interaction system.
- SQL Backend (obviously)

  - PostgreSQL seems like a pretty good choice, as from what I've read, it's structure is a bit more "object-oriented" than, say, MySQL. Then again, I've used MySQL before and haven't had much problem with it whatsoever. Would it be worth learning PostgreSQL for this purpose?
- Java or .Net implementation (Preferably Mono, so I can use .Net while hosting the website using Apache).

  - The reason for this is because, frankly, while I know PHP is a great platform to develop websites with, *I hate developing with it*. Before someone chimes in and flames me for saying that, note that I have nothing against the language, I just don't like it for *my* purposes.
  - While Mono may be good to go with, I'm aware that ASP.Net MVC 3 hasn't been released for Mono yet, which may be a pain to work with, without their Razor syntax. Ontop of that, it seems Java is completely FULL of class libraries which deal with web development, that can be downloaded from the web. If anyone has any experience with these, I'd appreciate if that were posted. From what I've read about Spring and Struts2, they seem to be the best out there - especially since they're (AFAIK) MVC.
  - I've considered Python and Django, which do seem REALLY nice, but I don't know much Python, and I'd rather start with something that I already know (language-wise; not framework-wise) than dive into learning a language AND a new framework.
  - I'd REALLY like to be able to host my website via Apache, rather than using Windows Server or anything like that, as, frankly, I hate their setup. I'm not dissing it in any way, shape, or form, I'm just saying I dislike it. <3 terminal config. If there is a good reason to with Windows Server, however, I'd be willing to learn it.
  - C# has a lot of things that Java appears not to have, including Delegates, unsigned types, and LINQ. Is there anything that Java has which can counter these?

Comment: Pick whatever you like. It doesn't matter. They're all used successfully. The platform you pick will not impact your project. They're all awesome, they all suck. They're all slow/fast/feature-rich/poor. So, it doesn't matter. Pick whatever you like. You make the platform work, the platform doesn't make you work. The project will succeed because of you, your skill, and your effort, not the platform. Pick what you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going with Java, you can't host with apache. You'll run Tomcat or some other servlet container, or a full Java EE application server such as Glassfish. You can have apache act as a front end for the requests with a more efficient protocol (ajp protocol) than just making an http call.

Never used Mono, haven't done a ton of reading, but if you want to use ASP.NET, I'd just go with Windows. Save the hassle.

Frankly, you can easily just make the backend a set of APIs and the UI very ajaxian based to interact with the backend in a way that will let you switch between backend languages easily. So, if you're very comfortable in ASP.NET, do it up in that so you can get it running, and then later on when you want to switch hosting re-implement (with lots of lessons learned I'm sure) in Java or Django or whatever.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I think I'll settle with ASP.Net and MsSQL Server then. Much appreciated :)

Comment: You might still want to consider mySQL to reduce your startup costs (e.g. licensing), although if there are certain needs that aren't being me, then by all means go with MSSQL. Realistically though, for a pretty basic relation DB, mySQL should do just fine. Just remember to use InnoDB as your table type.

Answer (score 2):

**"write my own simple credit-card interaction system"**

Do you realize how many privacy, security, legal and compliance issue this involves?

Comment: Then what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Integrate with a trustworthy and popular payment system. Accept the fees as part of doing business. Spend your time(read "money") developing the unique and valuable part of your site.

Answer (score 2):

This is my favorite stack, it absolutely flies. I highly recommend it:

- Twitter BootStrap
- Facelets2.0/JSF2.0
- CDI
- JPA

You could even host it on http://jelastic.com/ using GlassFish. They're a really innovative cloud hosting provider. Take 30 seconds to look at their front page to see why.

MySQL/PostgreSQL: Go with whatever your familiar with. If you use pure JPA and JPQL, you can switch at anytime to a different backend database.

Paypal: How about Dwolla, Chargify, or Google Checkout?

I know I'll burn for saying this, but I'd advise again Django/Python for a couple of reasons. I'm currently involved in a major site with it and it's a mess. First, Python tooling isn't near at the caliber as Java tooling. Second, Django is much too restrictive, and template tags can't even hold a candle to the awesome AJAX offerings of Facelets2.0/JSF2.0. Third, it's not really all that fast to execute, nor is it "hyper productive" as it's advertised. It's ok for small things, but you'll outgrow it quickly.

Comment: Huh...Twitter BootStrap looks pretty nifty. Maybe I'll have to download it and play around with it. Can't make my designs look any worse at least!

Answer (score 2):

My $0.02:

If you are developing (or have the resources) then go with "what you have" as far as expertise is concerned. Don't get "religion" when it comes to "platform" - use what you have best expertise in. A more fundamental question is "build vs buy" - yes, you **can** code like the best of them, but *is that your (business) goal*?

1. Paypal - I'm not sure what you mean by "expensive" but as @Desmond Zhou stated, unless you are in the business of creating a payment processing system, you shouldn't even consider creating your own credit card interaction system. Use established services like Paypal or 3rd party alternative checkout flows from [Google](http://www.google.com/payments/index.html) or [Amazon](http://www.amazonservices.com/content/amazon-checkout-payments.htm).
2. Along the lines of "build vs buy" - You can use "seller platforms" - from eBay (stores) or Amazon and not spend a single minute on development and just "get going" **now**. Yes, they will hit you with fees - but so will hosting, whatever time you spend with multiple hats - business owner/developer/IT person. There is always that "hidden cost" with us geeks and we tend to forget that we're running a business (unless the business in fact is code/software).
3. Technology platform/stack - **If** you **must develop** as above, go with your available expertise so you can start the business of starting your business instead of dealing with the learning curve. Make decisions that consider the long view - why are you considering Mono over "native" for .Net? To save a few bucks on hosting? We geeks like to think about "we can just migrate" - of course, that's our nature. But do you realize the cost and effort that would involve? e.g. switching databases - do they support the same data types? encryption? Often what you start with is what you live with for a *long time*.
4. I **think**(?) you're a WISA (Windows/IIS/SQL/ASP.NET) person (as am I). I think WISA has come a long way as a platform, and community (Codeplex), **and** bringing costs down. Not ready for full blown SQL SVR, there's Express and even Compact (great embedded db and goes along the same dev/management tools as its bigger MS brethren). Its still not as cheap as LAMP but hopefully that's not how you make decisions on your platforms - go with what you know - avoid religion. You can make whatever language you have expertise in "fly" and if you know the platform, fly faster/higher.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hmm...You definitely have a point; I think I'll go with what makes the most sense in terms of getting things up and running. I'm actually neither a Linux guy nor a WISA dude; I'm fluent in both, as I think they both have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: To compliment that; I mistakenly stated I was fluent in *both*, where as in reality I'm more fluent with a LAMP setup as opposed to, say, Windows Server and IIS.